# How to merge hash with activerecord relations in controller / scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash

- I have **Item** model(table) with column [id,name,notes]. then I have hash lets call it **stock** with column [id_of_item,total_stock],
- when I do query in controller I would like to join the hash into the table as additional column so I can show the total_stock of the item.
- I prefer not to use map/each (looping through all the items since the items table has thousand records. I still don't know whether this possibly or not, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your stock is
`[[1, "total_stock_1"], [2, "total_stock_2"]]`
you should use
`stock = Hash[[[1, "total_stock_1"], [2, "total_stock_2"]]]`
to translate your `hash` to this style
`stock = {1 => "total_stock_1", 2 => "total_stock_2"}`

```
stock = {1 => "total_stock_1", 2 => "total_stock_2"}
@items = Item.all.map{|item| item.attributes.merge({total_stock: stock[item.id]})}
# the output will be a json not a ActiveRecordRelation
[
  {:id => 1, :name => 'item1', :notes => xxx, :total_stock => "total_stock_1"},
  {:id => 2, :name => 'item2', :notes => yyy, :total_stock => "total_stock_2"}
]
```

Comment: thanks, as information from my question above, I have defined the key and the value of the hash , stock hash key is the_id_of_the_item and the value is the total stock of the item

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in controller:

```
 @items = Item.all
 render json: @items.map{|item| {'item': item.as_json.merge stock.select{|item| item['id_of_item'] == item.id}['total_stock']} }}
```

Comment: thanks, I have no problem if it's just one item record(show), the one that I asked above is for index controller, merge the content of items with the content of hash.

Comment: Changed the answer for index action.